# ツールチップの文章が折り返されていない箇所がある

Tags: バグ, デザイン

### 不具合事象

ユーザーページのアクティビティタブにあるツールチップの中に、文章が折り返されずはみ出しているものがありました。現状では次の画像のようになっています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

### 補足情報 (OS, ブラウザのバージョンなど)

不具合が再現した OS, ブラウザは以下のとおりです。

- Windows 10
- Google Chrome 96.0.4664.110
- Opera 82.0.4227.23

Comment: 英語版等の別サイトでも再現する一方、私が SOja で自分のプロフィールページを開くと "目標にするタグバッジを選択" と表示されますね。 / 折り返すよりかはツールチップ自体を広げるか、短いテキストに見直す方がよいのかなと思います。